# How not to hardcode regex values to a string replace in lodash?

Tags: lodash

```
let test = L.replace( '[[Hi, Fred]]', /,|\[|\]/g, '' )
// => Hi fred
```

As you see this code removes all [ , and ].
How could I pass those characters to be removed, so they are not hardcoded but passed for example, from a function argument ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can escape the characters with `_.escapeRegExp` and then use a character class to remove the characters you don't want.

```
function removeChars(string, chars) {
  return _.replace(string, new RegExp('[' + _.escapeRegExp(chars) + ']', 'g'), '');
}
```

```js
function removeChars(string, chars) {
  return _.replace(string, new RegExp('[' + _.escapeRegExp(chars) + ']', 'g'), '');
}

console.log(removeChars('[[Hi, Fred]]', ',[]'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.13.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Or use `_.reject` to filter out characters that are included in a blacklist.

```
function removeChars(string, chars) {
  return _.reject(string, _.partial(_.includes, chars)).join('');
}
```

```js
function removeChars(string, chars) {
  return _.reject(string, _.partial(_.includes, chars)).join('');
}

console.log(removeChars('[[Hi, Fred]]', ',[]'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.13.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```